# LinqPad CRM 2011 Won't connect to server

Tags: c#, linq, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, linqpad

I just bought [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and downloaded the CRM 2011 plugin for it.  When I import it and try to use it to connect to my remote CRM server.  CRM is hosted on an external server and it works 100% fine in IE.

I CANNOT authenticate with the server in LINQPad because the Authentication groupbox is not enabled for some odd reason.  The whole groupbox: checkbox, text boxes, etc.  I copy and paste the exact url that is failing in the LINQPad plugin and it works immediately in IE.  What is going on and why can't I enter my credentials in the plugin?

I get the error: `"http://servername:port123/orgname" is not a valid CRM organization URL.`

I have tried both the latest release and debug versions of LINQPad and I am using version 1.0.0.0 of the MS CRM 2011 plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The link no longer works. You need to copy the 2 files mentioned below to the following folder,

C:\ProgramData\LINQPad\Drivers\DataContext\4.0\CrmLINQPadPlugin (adfe55fce9cb9a0f)

I am not 100% sure about the name of the CrmLINQPadPlugin folder, but it should be along those lines.

I had a similar issue and the following thread fixed it for me:

[MSDN discussion thread](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/crmlinqpad/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=4969)

Copying CrmSvcUtil.exe and Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll to appropriate folder allowed me to connect.

Comment: It seems that link does not work. Could you add the information as to where you needed to copy those files?

Answer (score 0):

Along with the plugin, make sure you have the [Windows Identity Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17331) installed. Also, there is a similar question posed [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/crmlinqpad/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=4381).

Comment: +1 for the great link, which details what LINQPad is doing in the background. I like how in the linked forum post, the OP says it's fixed, but doesn't leave any information about what he did to fix it!

Comment: Lovely description of how he fixed the issue.  I also have WIF installed.

Comment: Also, I've installed everything I need.  I still can't connect.

Comment: @Sef Have you tried writing a test app doing what the MS dev recommends (in the linked article), then seeing if that works? If it doesn't work, then you know the issue isn't LinqPad.